# What is the difference between Computer Architecture and Computer Organisation?

Tags: computer-science, terminology

Is there any difference between the terms(or subjects) Computer Architecture and Computer Organization? If yes, what is it? Please Explain me in detail. These two seem to be quite similar fields. Tell them apart by quoting good sources.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [the Wikipedia entry *Microarchitecture*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microarchitecture):

> In computer engineering, **microarchitecture** (sometimes abbreviated to µarch or uarch), **also called computer organization**, is the way a given instruction set architecture (ISA) is implemented on a processor. A given ISA may be implemented with different microarchitectures. Implementations might vary due to different goals of a given design or due to shifts in technology. **Computer architecture is the combination of microarchitecture and instruction set design.**

(emphasize mine)

See the whole article for more in-depth details. See also the [*computer architecture* article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_architecture).